# How to show a specific no row overlay with ag-grid?

Tags: angular, overlay, ag-grid

I need to show a specific message when there are no users found with ag-grid in Angular6.

This is my code:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.gridOptions.frameworkComponents.loadingCellRenderer = TableLoadingComponent;
  this.rowBuffer = 0;
  this.rowSelection = 'multiple';
  this.rowModelType = 'infinite';
  this.paginationPageSize = 10;
  this.cacheOverflowSize = 2;
  this.maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests = 1;
  this.infiniteInitialRowCount = 10;
  this.maxBlocksInCache = 2;
   
  this.overlayLoadingTemplate =
    '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while your rows are loading</span>';
  this.overlayNoRowsTemplate =
    '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center" style="font-size: 20px"><i class="fa fa-window-close"></i> Empty data</span>';
}
```

I need to show "No users found" where it says "Empty data", only in my users list component

```html
<div class="card-body" style="height: 400px;">
  <ngb-alert [type]="alert?.type" *ngIf="alert" (close)="alert = null">{{alert?.message}}</ngb-alert>
  <app-table (readyGrid)="onGridReady($event)" (dbclickemitter)="edit($event)" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
  </app-table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add your `<span>No users found</span>` HTML element directly in your template with an `*ngIf="users && users.length === 0"`, can update your question and show where/how your data rows are managed?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `[overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"` to your ag-grid template. like in this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-bss-test-rb1jtp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

In this example, we will first see the message:

```
Please wait while your rows are loading
```

And then 6 seconds later, you will see your data loaded.

> initially, `rowData` is set to `null` and then in your case, if you still not able to find any data, you will not provide then `rowData` with a new value, and the message `Please wait while your rows are loading` will still showing. You can replace `Please wait while your rows are loading` with `No users found`

I used `setTimeout` here just to simulate a service that will get result after some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
   showNoRowsMessage(): void {
    if (this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() === 0) {
        (this.gridApi as any).gridOptionsWrapper.setProperty('overlayNoRowsTemplate', 'custom message');
    }
}
```

Then call it in the GridReady method:

```
    onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent): void {
    ...
    this.showNoRowsMessage();
}
```

No other addition in the gridOptions / template